# WebClient FileUpload - problem with upload file

Tags: c#, webclient, iformfile

I'm trying to upload files with WebClient on network disc.
Everything is fine until I publish my app.
Code to upload:

```cs
public IFormFile Image{ get; set; }
(...)
imagename = FileHelper.GenerateFilename(Image.FileName);
var imgsave = Path.Combine(PathHelper.NewsFilePath, imagename);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

try
{
    client.UploadFile(imgsave, Image.FileName);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

When I run application locally, it's working perfect, but when I publish my app, I get an error:

```
Error message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\test.PNG'. 
File name: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\test.PNG' at (...)
```

Seems that published app is looking for this file somewhere within app folder. How can I indicate this file to upload it correctly?

Comment: Is this code running inside your web application? Then this code dows not belong there but in some sort of a client app (console, web, yo u name it)

Comment: Microsoft discourages the use of `WebClient` in new code.

Comment: @Sascha yes I think so, this is web app wrote in Razor-Pages

Comment: @Fildor what can I use instead nowadays?

Comment: HttpClient is the recommended substitute

Comment: @Fildor have you got maybe any example of how upoad file with HttpClient?